# How to Redirect to a url containing an anchor (#)?

Tags: mod-rewrite, encoding, url-rewriting

I need to take standard incoming urls and <strike>rewrite</strike> redirect them to target specific anchors on a single page (incoming html page name becomes the anchor name).  E.g., the rule would be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^files/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.html$ /test.html#$1 [R]
```

So this url:

```
http://foo.com/files/bar.html
```

...would become:

```
http://foo.com/test.html#bar
```

The rule itself works fine, but the # character gets encoded in the browser address bar to:

```
http://foo.com/test.html%23bar
```

which of course does not work correctly as an anchor.  Is there a way in .htaccess to force it not to encode the hash?  I also tried escaping it like `\#` but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the noescape (NE) flag in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^files/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.html$ /test.html#$1 [NE, R]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I figured it had to be something simple, but Google was not showing me the way ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use `NE`, or No Escape flag:

`RewriteRule ^files/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.html$ /test.html#$1 [NE,R]`

Comment: Pat beat me by 57 seconds ;) Let the world know SO's "new answers" warning takes longer than that!