# URL Redirection with character % in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, url, character, redirect

I need to redirect multiple URLs with% character, through htaccess.

Currently the lines are:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-F

RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-D

RewriteRule ^-.*$ url [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^%20.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^%22.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^images/files/myname%is-fyle.pdf.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]

From these lines, the redirects do not work are:

RewriteRule ^%20.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^%22.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^images/files/myname%is-fyle.pdf.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? My knowledge is basic almost, not quite understand why the redirects with % in the URL do not work.

I researched on the use of flags as noescape [NE], but I have not managed to get the redirects from the URLs with the character %.

("url redirection" in te lines of htaccess is the URL that being new to the forum I can not post).

Thank you.

Sep 23: I thank those who have helped me with this problem. However, the URLs with special characters (% and ?) and capital letters do not forward.

**I copy and paste the complete code for my htaccess file**:

Here: http://pastebin.com/yXGQiQzd

I saw in this post [How to Redirect to a url containing an anchor (#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291158/how-to-redirect-to-a-url-containing-an-anchor) that apparently the answer is posted. However, the matter is in the use of **([])** for the rule. The example is: **([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)**

In my case, for example, these URLs:

images/SchoolContry/wef/pdf/SomethingOfFiles/the reasons behind?s of the ca?da.pdf
images/stories/Money/memo Matric?cula 2010.doc

Any idea why URLs with special characters (% and ?), space and capital letters redirect not?

Thanks.

Comment: How does `%` appear in your URL? Share a dummy source and dummy rewritten URL.

Comment: However, without being able to continue to redirect URLs like:

example/example/Example/example\%example.pdf

I tried in this way, without achieving results:

RewriteRule ^example/example/Example/example\%example.pdf.*$ url redirection [R = 301, L]

Comment: Does it have any relationship to use initial capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

URL encoded characters get decoded before they're sent through the rewrite engine. That means you need to use the decoded characters to match against and not the encoded ones. So for:

```
RewriteRule ^%20.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]
```

you want:

```
RewriteRule ^\ .*$ url redirection [R=301,L]
```

and for:

```
RewriteRule ^%22.*$ url redirection [R=301,L]
```

you want:

```
RewriteRule ^\".*$ url redirection [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jon Lin, helped me a lot!

However, without being able to continue to redirect URLs like:

example/example/Example/example\%example.pdf

I tried in this way, without achieving results:

RewriteRule ^example/example/Example/example\%example.pdf.*$ url redirection [R = 301, L]

Why do you think that is? (sorry, my english is bad)

Comment: Does it have any relationship to use initial capital letters?

Comment: @JoshuaProvoste Aside from the spaces in the square brackets, everything else looks fine.

Comment: Yes, what of the spaces is a detail. However, not forward. I'll edit the post to add the complete code for htaccess.