# Friendly URL and Anchors

Tags: html, .htaccess, anchor

Im' trying to achieve that the document goes to the anchor name given with a friendly URL.

`RewriteRule ^files/page/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?$ myPage.html#$1`

But this doesn't works.

I tried it inserting the url with the page: `myPage.html#myAnchor` and worked fine. So the problem must be in the htaccess line.

I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291158/how-to-redirect-to-a-url-containing-an-anchor) old question with an answer that seems it works, but unfortunately not for me.

HTACCESS file (updated with [L] flags):

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ahorro/?$ ahorro-para-mi-futuro.html [L]
RewriteRule ^ahorro/como-es-nuestro-ahorro/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?/?$ como-es-nuestro-ahorro.html#$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ahorro/preparado-para-tu-jubilacion/?$ hasta-que-punto-estas-preparado-para-tu-jubilacion.html [L]
RewriteRule ^ahorro/ventajas-fiscales/?$ ventajas-fiscales.html [L]
RewriteRule ^ahorro/para-mi-futuro/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?/?$ por-que-deberia-ahorrar-para-mi-futuro.html#$1 [NE,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^preparar-jubilacion/?$ preparo-mi-jubilacion.html [L]
RewriteRule ^preparar-jubilacion/calcula-tu-patrimonio/?$ calcula-tu-patrimonio.html [L]
RewriteRule ^preparar-jubilacion/calculadora-gastos/?$ calculadora-de-gastos.html [L]
RewriteRule ^preparar-jubilacion/disponibilidad-de-ahorros/?$ como-podre-disponer-de-mis-ahorros.html [L]
RewriteRule ^preparar-jubilacion/4-pasos-para-mi-jubilacion/?$ 4-pasos-para-planificar-tu-jubilacion.html [L]

RewriteRule ^vivir-jubilacion/?$ vivo-mi-jubilacion.html [L]
RewriteRule ^vivir-jubilacion/prioridades/?$ que-necesito-y-cuales-son-mis-prioridades.html [L]
RewriteRule ^vivir-jubilacion/disponer-de-mis-ahorros/?$ como-podre-disponer-de-mis-ahorros.html [L]
RewriteRule ^vivir-jubilacion/4-pasos-para-mi-jubilacion/?$ 4-pasos-para-planificar-tu-jubilacion.html [L]

RewriteRule ^encuentros/?$ encuentros-futuros.html [L]

RewriteRule ^calculadoras-y-simuladores/calculadora-ahorro/?$ calculadora-de-ahorro.html [L]
RewriteRule ^calculadoras-y-simuladores/calculadora-gastos/?$ calculadora-de-gastos.html [L]
RewriteRule ^calculadoras-y-simuladores/calcula-tu-patrimonio/?$ calcula-tu-patrimonio.html [L]

RewriteRule ^politica-cookies/?$ politica_cookies.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what it is happening, **epic facepalm**.

The `#` it's commenting all the things after it, so, it's logical that it is not working. The way to solve it, adding `#` inside the REGEX.

```
RewriteRule ^ahorro/para-mi-futuro/?(\#[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?/?$ por-que-deberia-ahorrar-para-mi-futuro.html$1 [NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with NE (No Escape) flag

```
RewriteRule ^files/page/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?$ myPage.html#$1 [NE,NC,L]
```

**source :**

Apache Rewrite flags : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: No luck, just the same as the other answer says, with the NE flag still not working

Comment: Whats not working? what is the url you are trying to rewrite? Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: The url would be like: `localhost/ahorro/para-mi-futuro/poblacion`. Yes, there are other Rewrite rules but none interfering with this one: `RewriteRule ^ahorro/para-mi-futuro/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?$ por-que-deberia-ahorrar-para-mi-futuro.html#$1 [NE,NC,L]`. just testing it in local

Comment: Not working it means that it's not going to the anchor when the page loads. If I write the page `myPage.html#anchor` (for example) it does

Comment: Well,the rule is working fine with NE flag on my apache server, Can you post your full htaccess file?

Comment: The problem is that your all rewrite rules are without flags , try adding L flag to each rules, L (LAST)flag is important as it tells the server to stop matching other rewrite ruls if it has already matched One,

Comment: The others are working properly. I'll try it in a few minutes and let you know about it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: found the problem and made a hotfix, posted the answer! Thanks for your help and the advices from `[L]`!